# Methods for matching networks for high power RF

Tags: rf, impedance-matching

I've got a fairly beefy induction heater (100-400 KHz, 5 kW output) that uses 1/4 inch copper tubing (and a coil) to a power head to deliver RF power to a workpiece. It's an older piece of equipment, and because it's an induction heater, it has a power output figure but no reflected power. It also has some minimal tuning capability (it auto-adjusts the frequency to optimize output).

I'm repurposing it as a power source for an ICP torch. I've done some work with matching networks at much higher frequences (2.45 GHz, 10 GHz, 20 GHz) and in general have some working knowledge of how to design those for waveguide or coax.

What sort of components are useful for matching at this frequency and power level? I can imagine maybe using a variable vacuum capacitor. But I have to admit my imagination fails me when thinking of how to transition from the copper tube form factor to some coaxial cable (7/16 DIN?). Copper strip brazed to the tubing that gets brazed to the center pin of a solder jack connector?

The secondary question is the implementation of power sensing. My assumption is that you would need to (because of the power level, and the low frequency) implement a coax directional coupler, likely with air as the dielectric (or maybe SF6) to inhibit breakdown / avoid thermal runaway with PTFE. Is that roughly the right approach?

Comment: Do you know how much voltage/field strength is needed to excite your ICP application?  At a guess, this frequency is much too low to do anything except at severely reduced pressure (is this at atmospheric pressure?).

Comment: @TimWilliams We've gotten it to work at "reasonable" pressures (significantly higher than a typical ICP reactor at 10 Pa) but without better coupling it's not going to get to atmospheric or higher (which is the goal). It's able to initiate breakdown at ~250A, but we haven't bothered finding the minimum.

Comment: To achieve higher voltages/currents on a given tank, the multiplication ratio is limited by the Q factor.  For most solid wire/tube coils, this is around 100-200. Most power supplies I think aren't made to couple to such high Q factors either, which may push you into a far corner of its operating range, where you then aren't generating enough MMF or EMF despite the high Q; or to modify the tuning network inside the supply; or it simple isn't stable into such a load. Q can be raised using litz in hose (water cooled).  Do you have any estimate for what V/I is required to achieve breakdown?

Comment: Also, what model of power supply is it, or what design does it seem to use?  (Might not be very useful, or very apparent how it's wired, but just for information.)

Comment: Not sure about the design. Its an Ambrell EasyHeat.

Comment: My best estimate for minimum power / amperage for breakdown is 500W / 150A, assuming you're asking as measured at the coil. Thats around a 0.05T mag flux density inside the discharge chamber.

Comment: Hm, do you have the remote heat station model? Do you know what's inside it -- just capacitors and bus bar, or anything else? Datasheet certainly seems to indicate it will do the current and power you ask for, but if that's at enough voltage / number of turns, might be another matter.

Comment: ...Wait, this whole thing is MUCH simpler than it's made out to be, isn't it? -- What is the ICP "torch" in the first place? Where do these impedance figures come from, most importantly: *at what frequency?* There you will find your answer.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have to be honest: my C- in microwave engineering (and lack of other EE coursework) is probably the reason you've left me in the dust with this one. 

If I refine the question, does it help? I'm not actually interested in how to match *this* power source (which we are misusing) to a torch, but rather some generic parallel-transmission line based generator (at ~400 KHz and 5 kW) to a varying complex impedance. I'm more used to waveguide & coax and am just curious how you'd do it - doesn't seem like there's an easy equivalent to a three stub tuner or a sliding short.

Comment: I mean, can you show the load, what is its circuit and component values, or failing that, physical dimensions (coil, turns, etc.)? Consider: a typical coil for that power supply is 1uH, at 400kHz that's 2 ohms reactance. You're assuming numbers WAY out of the ballpark -- something's gone amiss here. Or if your question is not about either of these units at all, then they are superfluous and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> *What sort of components are useful for matching at this frequency and
> power level?*

400 kHz has a wavelength of 750 metres and, given that it's likely you will come close to one-tenth (a rule of thumb) it's most likely that your reasons for wanting to match impedances are highly dubious.

At higher frequencies (like above 10 MHz usually) matching impedances is done to avoid signal reflections corrupting data transmission but, at 10 MHz that would involve a cable length of 3 metres or longer.

So, figure out why you think you need to perform any impedance matching. Tuning for resonance is certainly something you'll likely to have to do but not impedance matching.

> *I can imagine maybe using a variable vacuum capacitor.*

Are you sure you don't mean tuning for resonance?

> *The secondary question is the implementation of power sensing. My
> assumption is that you would need to (because of the power level, and
> the low frequency) implement a coax directional coupler*

These rely on the length of the coupler being about the same order as the wavelength and, 750 metres seems unfeasible in that respect.

Comment: Bunch of responses, probably revealing that I am at best a hack at RF.

1 - Impedance matching - in ICP literature, this is generally what people refer to, rather than tuning for resonance. Most ICP sources are 13.56 MHz, but the coils tend to be << 3 meters, and still employ L matching networks. I've also seen some references to CCP discharges at 450 KHz using the same. We generally "know" we need to do this because very little power is coupled to the plasma otherwise (measurably).

If not able to measure power by directional coupler, what other methods are there for this frequency?

Comment: Also, I didn't do enough googling - there are a bunch of low power directional couplers in existence for this frequency range in small form factors, from Minicircuits and others. How are they able to implement them?

Comment: @phyllisdiller OK, let's run with impedance matching; what impedance values?

Comment: The plasma density (and thus impedance) in the reactor will vary with different input powers / pressures. Would likely need to have something that could tune to Z = 50 + 150j or Z = 75 + 200j.

Comment: Two impedance values are needed plus a schematic of the reactor. Imagine I know nothing about things except L-pads and impedance matching. What gets matched to what in other words?

Comment: Edited the question to clarify with impedances / circuit diagram.

Comment: FYI (for all concerned), the machine in question appears to be a "self tuning" or variable-frequency design: the basic structure is a VCO into a power inverter, with the VCO setpoint driven by error amp(s) tracking phase (thus making a PLL, which prevents the setpoint from passing through resonance), and any process variables of interest (usually voltage, current and power). *Adding any unexpected reactances to the work coil will likely confuse the controller, resulting in a fault condition* (it refuses to operate).

Comment: @phyllisdiller you should edit your question more carefully to show your additions as an edited section. This prevents folk reading it and thinking I've not addressed your full question. I'm going to roll back your edits to how they previously stood. You can bring them back into the question when you return. Also, I don't have any access to the linked document and, I suspect others don't either.